Proving that there are no integral points on a union of hyperbolas
I have a curve C: (x^2±x-y^2+1)(x^2∓x-y^2) where x,y ∈ Z+ that I want to prove has no non-trivial integral points other than (0,0),(1,0),(0,±1). I am having a hard time coming up with a solution.

At first, $x^2-x=(x-1)^2+(x-1)$ that reduces the question to the sign $+$. Next, $x^2+x-y^2$ is either at least $x$, if $y\leqslant x$, or at most $-x-1$, if $y>x$.

What is the equation of the curve? Please avoid the symbols $\pm$ and $\mp$, but do include an equation sign (necessary for an equation).

We can analyze each factor separately. For the first factor, $x^2 + x - y^2 + 1 = 0$, we get $y^2 = x^2 + x + 1 = (x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4}$. The minimum value of the right-hand side is $\frac{7}{4}$ when $x = 0$, yielding $y = \pm 1$. For the second factor, $x^2 - x - y^2 = 0$, we have $y^2 = x(x-1)$. For positive integers, this is a perfect square only when $x = 0$ or $x = 1$, giving solutions $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$. The third factor, $x^2 + x + y^2 = 0$, has only $(0,0)$ as a solution for non-negative integers, as the sum of three non-negative terms is only zero when all terms are zero. The fourth factor, $x^2 - x + y^2 = 0$, can be rewritten as $y^2 = x - x^2 = -x(x-1)$, which for integers is only possible when $x(x-1) = 0$, yielding solutions $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$

About your second sentence: the minimum value of the right-hand side is $1$, and this is achieved for $x\in{0,-1}$. More importantly, it is not clear from your argument why all the solutions come from the case when the right-hand side is minimal.
